# After moving to maven, my compiled jar file doesn't run

Tags: java, maven

It actually took me a long while to notice. When I run the project in netbeans, it works just as expected. But when I do the `Build` I get `PROJECTNAME-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` file that doesn't do anything. When unpacked, it looks like this:

[image: image description]

This is suspicious, before Maven, my compiled file looked like this:

[image: image description]

Shouldn't the `Main` class be in the jar file root? How does JVM know which main class to run?

There's something disturbing about the MANIFEST.MF too:

### Old manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.1
Created-By: 1.7.0_45-b18 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/alloy.jar lib/jna-platform.jar lib/jna.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: Main
```

### New manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: Jakub
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_31
```

Seems like `Main-Class` entry is missing...

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/.

Comment: are you using the correct maven layout for your project? Java files belong to `src/main/java` and resources to `src/main/resources`. See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Well, not exactly. I've put resources in `resources/` and java files in `src/`. But I've configured these paths in my [pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/E0B2tPaH).

Comment: Obviously you configuration has an error, otherwise, your classes would be contained in your JAR. Try applying the default maven layout.

Comment: @Alexander My classes were allways in the JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [maven-jar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Make) for make your `jar` executable. For me actual code below:

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>my.main.class</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/result</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Alse  usefull [exec-maven-plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/exec-maven-plugin):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <mainClass>my.main.class</mainClass>
      <!--
      <commandlineArgs>-d 5409  -c 467 -t 2  -dlg true</commandlineArgs>
      -->
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I added this and I also added some `maven-assembly-plugin` to bundle dependencies in my jar file. Still, double clicking my `.jar` doesn't have any effect. Do you have any idea what should I look for or how can I debug this issue?

Comment: Turns out that my program was additionally throwing an exception due to default config file missing. Now it works, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly many IDE's provide a simple mechanism for packaging all of your library jars into your main build jar. This is both frowned-upon and potentially hazardous to your deployable - you should really deploy all of the used libraries separately and use your class-path to join them all up.

As Maven attempts to make doing it right the easiest way it is designed to by default build your jar to contain just your code and no more. If you can stick with this solution then it may be worth your while doing so.

However, sometimes it is necessary to make this happen, perhaps to duplicate existing build results while switching to Maven or maybe deployment is enough of a nightmare without having to deploy dozens of libraraies too. To achieve this you can build what the Maven community call an Uber-Jar using the Maven Shade plugin.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <!-- Make sure jaxb is included. -->
              <artifact>com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl</artifact>
              <includes>
                <include>*.*</include>
              </includes>
            </filter> 
            <filter>
              <!-- Make sure jtds is included. -->
              <artifact>net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds</artifact>
              <includes>
                <include>**</include>
              </includes>
            </filter> 
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.sf</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.dsa</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.rsa</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Note that building uber-jars is generally not the best approach - there are many discussions about this online. Also there are many relational problems with the `maven-shade-plugin` itself as it interferes with Maven's mechanism for determining dependencies.

That said - if you must do it then the shade plugin is your guy.

NB: Just because this excludes licences does not mean this is a good idea - this is there to avoid duplicate file name issues in the uber jar.

See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/) interesting blog by MKYong about the pros and cons of using `assembly/shade/one-jar`.

Comment: In other words I shouldn't be building my jar with all the dependencies bundled? Does `maven-shade-plugin` conflict with `maven-assembly-plugin` I use to build the "Uber jar"?

Comment: @TomášZato - I would not go so far as **shouldn't**, It is just not recommended. Not sure how it might interact with the assembly plugin - [MKYong](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-shade-plugin/) says *Maven Shade plugin is a better plugin to create fat/uber jar, if compare with assembly plugin, because it provides class relocating feature, to avoid same class name conflict in the classpath.*